# Is bootcamp 6.0 supporting Target Display mode of an Imac to a Windows 10 OS?

Tags: bootcamp, imac, thunderbolt, target-display

I have a 2014 iMac with a Bootcamp version 6.0 installed. I want to use it as a display for a MacBook Pro running windows 10 via thunderbolt to thunderbolt cable. Is that possible? or only works from OS-X to OS-X? Can someone refer me to a official documentation that states that this is supported or has done it themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible. Target display mode only works if both machine are in macOS, as mentioned in the Apple KB article [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204592).

> If your iMac is currently started up in Windows, it won't enter Target Display Mode. Target Display Mode isn't supported in Boot Camp.

Comment: the iMac will start in OS-X, it's the MacBook Pro the one that is running windows and I want that uses the IMac as a display

Comment: @FrankS101 I tried that one as well myself, it also doesn't work. You needs both machines to be in macOS for it to work.

Comment: Did you try with a thunderbolt - thunderbolt connection or what cable did you use to connect them both?

Comment: @FrankS101 Yes, I used a Thunderbolt cable to join my MacBook Pro (Mid-2012) and iMac (Late 2013). It work when both are in macOS but doesn't when one of them is in Windows.